# how i can pass a parameter to my SQL query in where clause using ANT script

Tags: ant

My ant script is:

```
<property name="log.file.name" value="${cacsbatch.log.dir}/RequestPurgeProcessor_${DSTAMP}_${TSTAMP}.log" />
<property file="project.property" value="${cacsbatch.request.detail.purge.days}"/>

<record name="${log.file.name}" action="start" append="no" loglevel="info" />

<target name="main">
    <exec executable="sqlplus"  failonerror="true">
        <arg value="@script\RequestPurger.sql"/>
        <arg value="${cacsbatch.request.detail.purge.days}"/>
        </exec>
</target>
```

and SQL query is:

```
Delete from TABLE_NAME where date < &cacsbatch.request.detail.purge.days
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete from TABLE_NAME where date < to_date('&1','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Your date format may differ, like your mileage.  But if your parameter is in fact a number of days, then:

```
Delete from TABLE_NAME where date < sysdate - &1;
```

Comment: thanks for reply..as i have to delete a record on compare to two date and if the date is greater than 7 day then the record should be deleted ..

Comment: error is : [echo] Accessing secure value for: XWPHXCACSDEV76
     [exec] SELECT * FROM PRINT_REQUEST WHERE TO_CHAR(LAST_UPDT_DATE_TIME_STAMP,
'YYYYMMDD')<=TRUNC((SELECT SUBSTR(AST.TRANSACTION_DATA,28,8) AS DATE_TIME FROM A
CCT_SYSTEM_TRANS AST WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(PS.PARN_GUID,1,6) FROM PRINT_
REQUEST PS WHERE ROWNUM=1)=SUBSTR(AST.TRANSACTION_DATA,1,6) AND SUBSTR(AST.TRANS
ACTION_DATA,25,3)=100))- C:\Dev\CACS\CACSBatch\deploy\datalib\RequestPurger.sql
     [exec]


     [exec] ERROR at line 1:
     [exec] ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
     [exec]
     [exec]

Comment: sql is 
 SELECT * FROM PRINT_REQUEST WHERE TO_CHAR(LAST_UPDT_DATE_TIME_STAMP,'YYYYMMDD')<=TRUNC((SELECT SUBSTR(AST.TRANSACTION_DATA,28,8) AS DATE_TIME FROM ACCT_SYSTEM_TRANS AST WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(PS.PARN_GUID,1,6) FROM PRINT_REQUEST PS WHERE ROWNUM=1)=SUBSTR(AST.TRANSACTION_DATA,1,6) AND SUBSTR(AST.TRANSACTION_DATA,25,3)=100))- '&1';

Comment: and ANT is
 <target name="purge-table">
  <timer name="[ Request Purge Processor]  - purge table ">
   <executeSql sqlFileName="RequestPurger.sql" sqlFilePath="${cacsbatch.datalib}"/>
   <property name="cacsbatch.request.detail.purge.days" value="${cacsbatch.request.detail.purge.days}"/>
  </timer>
 </target>
 <target name="main">
  <timer name="[Request Purge Processor]">
   <antcall target="purge-table" />
  </timer>
 </target>

Comment: the Parameter that i have to pass is 7 .

that i have updated in my property file with name cacsbatch.request.detail.purge.days

Comment: This SQL is somewhat different from the one you originally posted, is it not?  Please update your question.

Comment: yes.  i was tried that SQL earlier so i was posted there that only,

i tried with &1 as you suggested, and i got  the error .

Comment: in error , at the place of &1, its taking my whole SQL path

Comment: You cannot get this error `Accessing secure value for: XWPHXCACSDEV76 [exec] SELECT * FROM PRINT_REQUEST WHERE ...` from this query `Delete from TABLE_NAME where date < sysdate - &1;`

Comment: Sorry , I got issue with the SQL :SELECT * FROM PRINT_REQUEST WHERE TO_CHAR(LAST_UPDT_DATE_TIME_STAMP,'YYYYMMDD')<=TRUNC((SELECT SUBSTR(AST.TRANSACTION_DATA,28,8) AS DATE_TIME FROM ACCT_SYSTEM_TRANS AST WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(PS.PARN_GUID,1,6) FROM PRINT_REQUEST PS WHERE ROWNUM=1)=SUBSTR(AST.TRANSACTION_DATA,1,6) AND SUBSTR(AST.TRANSACTION_DATA,25,3)=100))- &1;

Comment: Is there any wrong in my ANT Script to passing the Parameter ?

Comment: It is strange that sqlplus sees the script name as parameter 1.  Of course, even so, just adding  `- &2` at the end of the SQL will not give you a correct syntax.

Comment: edit your question, put the correct script and the correct SQL in it.